# Spring security авторизация пользователя

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

Пытаюсь разобраться как реаизовать авторизацию, получилось сдлеать, но только работает до перезапуска браузера.

Искал в гугле примеры реализации авторизации для клиента на отдельном сервер, но везде одни и теже стати с JSP в итоге решил попробовать адоптировать один из них под себя и реализовал следующие классы
 `UserDetailsService`, `AuthenticationManager` и класс для авторизации `AuthenticateService`. ПОтом я решил доваить функцию rememberm-me, добавил настройки в конфиг, в базе добавилась таблица, но при авторизации не добавляется cookie и запись в базу. Может быть при использовании rememberm-me нужно использвать  не `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` или добавить какойто фильтр?
Так хотелось бы узнать какие именно интерфейсы\классы нужно использовать для авторизации через токены.

```
@Component
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        EntityUser user = userRepo.findByUsername(username);
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities =new ArrayList<>();

        for (EntityRole entityRole : user.getRoles()) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(entityRole.getRoleName()));
        }

        return new User(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(),grantedAuthorities);
    }
 }
```

---

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthentivationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetails customUserDetails;


    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        UserDetails userDetails =  (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (userDetails.getPassword().equals(authentication.getPrincipal())){
            authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
    }
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class AuthenticateService implements IAuthentivateService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthentivationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetails customUserDetails;


    @Override
    public String findLigInUsername() {
        Object userDetails = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
        if (userDetails instanceof UserDetails){
            return ((UserDetails) userDetails).getUsername();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean autologin(String username, String password) {
        UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetails.loadUserByUsername(username);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token
            = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,password,userDetails.getAuthorities());

        authenticationManager.authenticate(token);

        if (token.isAuthenticated()){
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теперь cookie отправляется на клиент и в базе токен тоже сохранятеся.
Сделал следующим образом:
1)Наследуемся от `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices` переопределяем метод `onLoginSuccess` и делаем его публичным.
2)создаем бин класса из п.1
3)В контроллере к параметрам метода который замапин к URL страницы логина добовляем `HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response`, например

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
    public void postLogin(@RequestBody EntityUser body, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
UserDetails userDetails = detailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,user.getPassword(),userDetails.getAuthorities());

        myTokenRememberMeService.onLoginSuccess(req,res,token);

        if (token.isAuthenticated())
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
}
```

4)создаем токен `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` заполняем и вызываем метод `onLoginSuccess` передав одним из параметров созданый токен, проверяем что аутентификация прошла и добавляем токен в security context.
P.S. У меня такое чуство что это жесткий костыль и можно сделать все гораздо проще, а пока работает и ладно))